# Getting 'ClassCastException' when using kotlin-faker with Generics Type in Android, How to Fix?

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

How to use kotlin-faker (https://github.com/serpro69/kotlin-faker/) to generate data with generics type like below?

```kotlin
data class BaseResponse<T>(
    val code: ResponseCode = ResponseCode.OK,
    val message: String = "",
    val error: String = "",
    val timestamp: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(),
    val data: T? = null,
    val status: String = ""
)

data class Car(
    val type: String = "",
    val color: String = "",
    val availableDate: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now()
)

object CarMock {

    fun carSuccess(faker: Faker): BaseResponse<Car> {
        return faker.randomProvider.randomClassInstance {
            typeGenerator<ZonedDateTime> {
                ZonedDateTime.now()
            }

            namedParameterGenerator("code") {
                ResponseCode.OK
            }

            faker.randomProvider.randomClassInstance<Car> { // <-- I think error from this
                typeGenerator<ZonedDateTime> {
                     ZonedDateTime.now()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run like

```kotlin
val faker = Faker()
val resultDetail = carSuccess(faker)
```

Then error like below

```
class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KTypeParameterImpl cannot be cast to class kotlin.reflect.KClass (kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KTypeParameterImpl and kotlin.reflect.KClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KTypeParameterImpl cannot be cast to class kotlin.reflect.KClass (kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KTypeParameterImpl and kotlin.reflect.KClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at io.github.serpro69.kfaker.provider.misc.RandomClassProvider.randomClassInstance(RandomClassProvider.kt:142)
```

I try many way but not work for me. I expected it's can work with generics type